# Linking ROS Noetic to opencv build from source

Tags: opencv, cmake, ros

I am writing a ROS node which uses OpenCV and SIFT (ROS Noetic, Ubuntu 20.04).
As of OpenCV version 4, the SIFT algorithm is part of the [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) package.
Within my ROS node, I want to use the ROS package cv_bridge, to convert between the OpenCV image format and ROS image sensor messages.

My understanding is that

1. Code in the opencv_contrib package is only usable if such package is built together with OpenCV from source.
2. cv_bridge depends on the Ubuntu package version of OpenCV, libopencv-dev.

I currently have both installed (the Ubuntu package and the version compiled from source) and I am trying to have my node depend on the source-compiled one, in order to use the non-free algorithms.
My procedure in order to do this is (after compiling OpenCV with the additional modules and OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON) adding to the CMakeLists.txt of my package the following lines:

```
find_package(OpenCV PATHS .../opencv-4.5.4/cmake)
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} .../opencv-4.5.4/include)
link_directories(.../opencv-4.5.4/lib)
add_executable(...)
target_link_libraries(nodeName ${catkin_LIBRARIES} .../opencv-4.5.4/lib)
```

in order to link my code to the compiled version of OpenCV. However, when I try to build it with `catkin build` I obtain:

```
In file included from [...]:
[...]/markerDetection.h:8:10: fatal error: opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp: No such file or directory
    8 | #include <opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp>
```

I suspect that ROS is trying to link to the version I installed through the package manager, which in fact does not have the `opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp` library.
Am I setting the wrong options in CMakeLists.txt? Is what I am trying to do even possible?

Comment: Not sure about that but maybe adding it to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable would help.
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH={ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}:path_of_your_new_hpp_files

Comment: Thanks for your input, but it doesn't work. My hypothesis is that it does not recognize the folder of the .hpp files as a ros package and therefore does not correctly process the files in there.

Comment: Ohh... it's pity to see how you trying to exploit a bad practice (e.g., hardcoding paths, building third parties during your build, using out-of-date commands which is not a modern CMake path, ...). Sorry, it gonna take to much time to explain everything, but probably you want/need to use [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) module... However, learn how to debug `find_package` with `--debug-find*`, or `--trace-*` options, and/or `CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE` variable to be sure what have you found.